# isnull() in pandas not able to identify blank value (Python coding)

Tags: pandas, isnull

```
import pandas as pd
t1=pd.DataFrame()
t1 ['name'] = ["dp","ag","wp"]
t1['status'] = ['a','b','c']
t1['age'] = [10,"",15]
t1
##
print(t1.isnull().values)
```

Why is the execution of this node not able to identify blank (see "age" column, 2nd row). isnull() is coming false for all the cells, see below output
Output:

```
 [[False False False] 
 [False False False] 
 [False False False]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because empty string is not same like missing value. So correct test for it is:

```
print(t1.eq('').values)
```

Or:

```
print((t1 == '').values)
```

If want test empty strings or missing values chain both mask with `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
print((t1.isnull() | t1.eq('')).values)
```

Comment: Thanks, but then what would a null look like in the dataframe? Because, even the space is not being captured by isnull() , nor the 'NULL' is being captured... I tried to check with that